# Can I turn off powershell 2.0

Tags: windows-10, security, powershell, windows-update, compatibility

Can I turn off powershell 2.0? 
Latest ACU up-to-date.
Does latest stable in-built powershell culmulates, supersedes, replaces 2.0, other old in it's entirety altogether. 
Isn't 2.0 vulnerable?
If so is there any reason why MS still included it, turned on by default in all latest builds, updates, which includes April update, as well as possibly all Insider, etc builds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can turn off powershell 2.0, and you should.

Instructions from: https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/windows_10/2017-04-28/finding/V-70637

> Fix Text (F-76869r1_fix)
>
> Disable "Windows PowerShell 2.0" on the system.
>
> Run "Windows PowerShell" with elevated privileges (run as administrator).
>
> Enter the following: Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root
>
> This command should disable both "MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root" and "MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2" which correspond to "Windows PowerShell 2.0" and "Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine" respectively in "Turn Windows features on or off".
>
> Alternately:
>
> Search for "Features".
>
> Select "Turn Windows features on or off".
>
> De-select "Windows PowerShell 2.0".

PowerShell 2.0 deprecation blog from Microsoft:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/08/24/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/

> We do not currently have a timeline to remove Windows PowerShell 2.0, but as we continue to evaluate its usage in the PowerShell ecosystem, we will be working to remove it in a future release.

PowerShell 2.0 will be completely removed in the future, but there is no timeline for this yet.

Comment: @Aoi. T_015: Was this what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you. Though it seems very stupid of MS that they kept it turned on by default even in April update